# Accessing lIghtning events from managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is it possible to handle an application event outside from the managed package.

I have created a managed package which have an Lightning event and a Lightning component, the Lightning component is firing this application event on a click.

How can I handle this event in another component?

I have handled the event but it is not working.

My event

```
<!--c:aeEvent-->
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
  <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

registering event in my controller

```
<aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:aeEvent"/>
```

these two codes belongs to a managed packages whose namespace is **appe**.

I am creating an component in another org where i have installed this managed package and in this component I am handling this event.

event handler

```
<aura:handler name="appEvent"  event="appe:aeEvent" action="{!c.handleApplicationEvent}"/>
```

but the function **handleApplicationEvent** is not getting invoked.
please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will most likely happen if you've either wrong access rules, namespace access or if the event is not registered properly. I would recommend checking the following

1) Is your component `access` attribute set to '`global`'

2) Try to debug if your event handler was registered successfully using the `<aura:registerEvent>` call

You can read more about Namespace usage in Lightning Components [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm).